# How to detect Adobe Reader popup using Powershell

Tags: powershell, adobe

When opening a PDF, Adobe Reader executes a structure check and, in case of a defect, a warning pops up. I need to know if a pop-up shows - preferably using Powershell - but do not need to catch its contents. Starting Adobe and getting the PIDs (yep, it´s two in secured mode) is easy. But Adobe´s behaviour differs e.g. from Office. I simply cannot find any child for the pop-up.

```
Get-Process AcroRd32 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
Where-Object {$_.Id -eq $Process.ID } |
Where-Object {$_.Responding -eq $true}
```

> Property "Responding" is True for the each AcroRd32 process. Always. Popup or no popup.

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process -Filter ("ParentProcessID=" + $Process.ID)
```

> No child.

How to get a handle on this popup? Preferably using Powershell (current: 4.0), maybe calling .Net to the rescue?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Best regards
Al

Based on feedback below, code was updated as follows and works so far:

```
    # Get installed Adobe version from registry
if ((Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).OSArchitecture -match "64-bit") 
    {
    $Key = "HKLM:\Software\WOW6432Node"
    } 
else 
    {
    $Key = "HKLM:\Software"
    }
$Key = $Key + "\adobe\Acrobat Reader"
if (Test-Path $Key) 
    { 
    $LatestVersion = ((get-childitem $Key) | sort-object -property Name | select-object -last 1).Name
    $Path = get-ItemProperty -Path ("Registry::" + $LatestVersion + "\Installer") | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Path"
    # Start Adobe Reader
    cd ($Path + "\Reader")
    .\AcroRd32.exe $File
    # Trying to get the popup
    foreach ($Process in (Get-Process AcroRd32))
{
# Takes really a lot of time for the pop-up up to open, 5s is on the safer side
sleep -s 5
if (([User32]::FindWindowByCaption($WindowCaption)).ToInt32() -ne 0)
    {
    write-host "Pop-up open for file $File"
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest separating shell code from your findings into [code blocks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) so strangers can copy your code and check what happens on their systems.

Comment: Here´s the not working code snippet if of any help`code`

Comment: One idea would be to [pinvoke user32.dll](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.FindWindow) and use some of the methods like `FindWindow()`

Comment: Hi BenH, thanks for feedback. So you see no way in Powershell either. Just what I feared. C# include works fine so far. Just hope it will survive the mass test. I paste the updated snipped to the query above. (Not enough characters allowed in comment). BR Al